# Failure/Error: expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Build a method that a new customer will use when entering the deli. The take_a_number method should accept two arguments, the array for the current line of people (katz_deli), and a string containing the name of the person wishing to join the line. The method should return the person's name along with their position in line. How can I arrange so that the array for the current line is equal to the count of the names array?

```html
katz_deli = []

def line(array)
  if array[0] == nil
   puts "The line is currently empty."
 end
end

def take_a_number(array, name)
  i=0 
  counter = 1
  while array.count != name.length 
    array[i] = counter
    i+=1 
    counter +=1 
  end
  if array.count > 1
    puts "The line is currently:"
  end
  name.each_with_index {|val, index| puts "#{index+1}. #{val}"}
  end
```

Here is the Rspec file:

```html
describe 'Deli Counter' do

  let(:katz_deli) { [] }
  let(:other_deli) { ["Logan", "Avi", "Spencer"] }

  describe "#line" do
    context "there is nobody in line" do
      it "should say the line is empty" do
        # This line checks the current standard output (your terminal screen)
        # to make sure the correct output has been puts'ed.
        expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with("The line is currently empty.")
        line(katz_deli)
      end
    end

    context "there are people in line" do
      it "should display the current line" do
        expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with("The line is currently: 1. Logan 2. Avi 3. Spencer")
        line(other_deli)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the wrong method ahead of time

```html
katz_deli = []

def line(array)
  if array.count > 1
   output = "The line is currently:"
   array.each_with_index {|val, index| output << " #{index+1}. #{val}"}
   puts output
   else 
     puts "The line is currently empty."
 end
end
```